# Variable limit for Johansen Test

Tags: cointegration, likelihood-ratio

I am investigating the variables count that I can use in Johansen test and accordingly in cointegration model. As it needs to critical values to compare with found statistics by test, I saw [1] which also used by MATLAB in jcitest. It has the critical values for until 12 variables. I am wondering that is there any studies to be alternative to it or for much more variables?

[1] MacKinnon, J. G., A. A. Haug, and L. Michelis. "Numerical Distribution Functions of Likelihood Ratio Tests for Cointegration." Journal of Applied Econometrics. v. 14, 1999, pp. 563-577